# Can you use the expression "unreliable narrator" as a metaphor to describe a real person?

Tags: metaphors

Can you use the expression “unreliable narrator” as a metaphor to describe a real person who’s relaying unreliable information?

For example:

> “TikTok alleges that they don’t send their user’s personal information to China. They are an unreliable narrator in my opinion but you should keep that in mind.“

Edit: just in case some of you don't know, unreliable narrator is a term from literature for when the narrator presenting the story isn’t credible. Here's a link to the wikipedia page if you want to read more:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreliable_narrator

Comment: What makes you think that you can't use the term “unreliable narrator” to describe a real person?

Comment: A narrator is a third party, not an interested *nogaya bedavar*. TikTok may be putting spin on their story, but as it's their PR, they are not narrating it. Still, you could use the term metaphorically here, to a friendly reader.

Comment: @YosefBaskin My intention is to use it metaphorically, I should have been more clear about it. I edited the post appropriately. Thanks :D

Comment: Why is this usage metaphorical? [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/narrator) has the broad definition '**narrator**: a person who gives an account or tells the story of events, experiences, etc' and it's people behind communications companies. [Etymon](https://www.etymonline.com/word/narration) says that 'narrare' means 'to make acquainted with', not just 'tell a story'.

Comment: narrators are not metaphors. Tiktok is not a narrator.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am not referring to the word narrator by itself. I am referring to the term unreliable narrator from literature. It is a term for a story where the narrator presenting the story isn’t credible.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreliable_narrator

Comment: I wonder how one distinguishes the free combination from the novel compound (which I admit I wasn't aware of)? 'Expression' covers both.  I'd say the compound is novel and rare enough to warrant a definition. // Given this, I'd say using a metaphorically broadened neonovel sense is unwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can, if it refers to a narrative. In your context better is “an unreliable source.”